# Selenium + C#, автотест логин

Tags: c#, selenium

Может кто подскажет как решить следующую задачу в автотесте.
Необходимо написать скрипт для входа в систему.
Данные необходимые для входа в систему - логин, пароль, а так же персональный идентификационный номер состоящий из 11 цифр(номер 1 на изображении).
Проблема состоит в том что при каждом новом входе система требует 2 рандомные цифры персонального идентификационного номера.
Отличия,когда поле активно(номер 2 на изображении) и неактивно(номер 3 на изображении).
То есть по просту когда поле активно для ввода отсутствует в описании элемента disabled="disabled".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Знаю что данное решение выполнимо при помощи цикла, потому пробовал выполнить данную задачу следующим способом:
Путём проверки включен ли компонент:

```
IWebElement peselSecondNumber = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='PESEL_1_txtContent']"));
            if (peselSecondNumber.Enabled)
            {
                peselSecondNumber.SendKeys("2");
            }
```

В общем это не сработало.
Пробовал так же как-то добавить в цикл if else то что текст disabled="disabled" отсутствует в активном компоненте, но там вообще белиберда получается.

Заранее благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Берете родителя этих дивов, берете всех его детей типа input, и выбрсываете задизабленых. У оставшихся смотрите id, на основе него получаете индексы цифры и вводите ее. Должно быть просто. Так как DOM вы показали не полностью, да еще и скриншотом, конкретное решение написать не удастся, только совет. Вот шпаргалка https://devhints.io/xpath, но я бы на CSS селекторах писал, если бы видел DOM.

Comment: Извиняюсь, что значит DOM?

Comment: `var elements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("input[name^=PESEL_]:not([disabled])"))`, как-то так

Comment: [DOM](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), другими словами все ваши теги

Comment: @aepot, если можете, напишите пожалуйста(в коде) как сравнит активный и неактивный элементы. Пример - активный <input class="form-control MNTextBoxContent" id="PESEL_5_txtContent" maxlength="1" name="PESEL_5" style="text-align: center;" type="password">

Comment: и неактивный <input class="form-control MNTextBoxContent" disabled="disabled" id="PESEL_6_txtContent" maxlength="1" name="PESEL_6" style="text-align: center;" type="password">

Comment: Я же написал как выбрать только активные выше.